# Check if parameter in command is declared/empty in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua, variable, parameters

I'm trying to check if a parameter is declared/empty using `lua`. So far I wrote the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\def\var#1{\def\@var{#1}}
%\var{Hello world}

\begin{document}
    \@var --
    
    \directlua{if string.len("\@var") == 0 then tex.print("empty") else tex.print("not empty") end}
\end{document}
```

If `\var{Hello world}` is uncommented the code runs with no errors, but if it's commented then it always returns error.

Is there a way to make this checking on a parameter/variable with `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: I don't know lua, but with regular latex, I would expect this to have all sorts of problems because https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do.  Could that be the problem here?

Comment: If I declare the command with no `@` it would lead to errors too.

Comment: As is, I'm getting the output: "var -".  If I uncomment that line, then I get the output: "Hello world - not empty".  I'm not quite sure what you think is happening.  Even if @ were a letter, I don't think this would work the way you want, because `\@var --` would be the same (I think) as `\@var{-}-`.  The only way to get an empty parameter is a literal `{}`.

Comment: I commented `\@var --` so it should print just the result of `\directlua` and the result is `Process exited with error(s)` after compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As wipet wrote you are missing \makeatletter. Apart from this you can get the content of a macro in lua with `token.get_macro`. Side remark: do not use standalone for such small examples. That is a complicated class with various side-effects. article is normally much better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\var#1{\def\@var{#1}}
\makeatother
\var{Hello world}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
    \@var --
\makeatother
    
    \directlua{
      a=token.get_macro("@var")
      print("XXXXXXXXXX @var is: ",a) %for debugging on the terminal
      if string.len(a) == 0 then 
       tex.print("empty") 
      else 
        tex.print("not empty " .. string.len(a)) 
      end}
   
    \var{}
      
      \directlua{
      a=token.get_macro("@var")
      print("XXXXXXXXXX @var is: ",a) 
      if string.len(a) == 0 then 
       tex.print("empty") 
      else 
        tex.print("not empty " .. string.len(a)) 
      end}
     
       
      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your line

```
\@var --
```

prints var – because the macro `\@` sets the spacefactor and then there are letters `v` `a` `r` and then space and the double `--` which is converted to the ligature `–`.

Your `\directlua` line works like this:

```
\directlua{if string.len("\spacefactor \@m {}var") == 0 then tex.print("empty") else tex.print("not empty") end}
```

because the `\directlua` primitive fully expands its argument before the argument is used.

If you use your macro `\var` (which is unused in your example), then the macro `\@` is redefined as a macro with mandatory separator `var`.

There are three cases described above, I mean that none of these case were your intention.

I can only guess your intend. Maybe, you want to define `\@var` macro when the `\var` macro is used and you want to test if the `\@var` macro is defined. You can't do this test using `\directlua` because you cannot put an undefined macro to the `\directlua` parameter because `\directlua` expands its parameter. You can do:

```
\catcode`\@=11 % `@` is letter
\def\var#1{\def\@var{#1}}

%\var{Hello world}  % this defines \@var as a macro with body Hello world.

\ifx\@var\undefined undefined var\else defined var \fi
```